# HTTP 200 but Access-Control-Allow-Origin denied with POST with Dribbble API

Tags: node.js, express, axios, cors, dribbble-api

I am working in Dribble's API and getting this error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://dribbble.com/oauth/token?client_id=08b8dec4ee5c7af3edd96e0a27eb97f8…a739&code=2806099a944253b647afe25ba384d68a90ca04158a1d1dceadddfe076de941f0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have already tried many different ways to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = '*'` but none of them worked for me, but reading the console.log(res._headers) i can see that it is being defined, i am sending this through a POST request but the header is not working. This one of the ways i have defined in app.js on Express v4 to set the header.

```
app.all("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "ETag, Link, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset");
  res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  return next();
});
```

And this is how i am sending the POST request with Axios:

```
export const postUserOAUTH = code => ((dispatch) => {
  axios({
    url: `https://dribbble.com/oauth/token?client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&code=${code}`,
    method: 'post',
  }).then((response) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'shots', payload: { registerResponse: response.data, token: response.data.access_token } });
    console.log('ok')
  }).catch((error) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'shots', payload: { registerResponse: error.message } });
    console.log('error')
  });
});
```

Edit:
Now the problem changed a little, the code status is 200, i received the token in response from my request by the API but still having the same error the code is still going inside the `.catch` not in the `.then`, i have attached a link of the [Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtQsE.png). I don't think this a problem about authentication since i am now getting the response that i want, but with this error i can't work with promises in my code. [Step 2. Dribbble redirects back to your site.](http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/oauth/#web-application-flow)

Comment: You are POST'ing to a Dribble server, your Express server has nothing to do with those requests. The "401" response suggests that it's an authentication error.

Comment: additionally, unless you have a separate route handling options requests, your current middleware wouldn't handle options requests properly.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you for the analysis, now i have changed the code and have the same problem but in a new way, i have attached an image to illustrate better this problem. [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtQsE.png), if you don't mind to have a new look.

Comment: @HugoNasciutti it looks to me like the OAuth endpoints for Dribbble aren't meant to be used through XHR. Perhaps you should contact Dribbble to ask if this is intentional (because the rest of their API _is_ CORS-enabled, from what I understand from their documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to set headers on the *response* object instead of the request (and the headers you are trying to set are headers that the server will set on a successful CORS request). Instead, try this:

```
app.all("/", function(req, res, next) {
  req.header("Origin", "*"); // ideally the '*' will be your hostname
  return next();
});
```

The server should then respond with the headers you were trying to set on the object.

Disclaimer: I don't know Express, this code may not work as written, but hopefully you get the idea.

For more info on CORS check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Also, you can see our example setting the `Origin` header here: http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/#cross-origin-resource-sharing

Cheers,

Ian

Developer @ Dribbble